# IPs allocated to specific countries. Can this change?

Tags: ip, maxmind

I know dynamic IPs change all the time - like if you restart your home broadband modem you will probably be assigned a new IP by your ISP.

But what about the allocation of these IPs by country?

Or in other words... **might an IP that is currently assigned to the UK (by doing a lookup) be assigned to say the US in a few years time?** Are IPs constantly being re-assigned across the world?

Why I'm asking:

I'm going through a huge database of transactions from 5 years ago. Each has an IP and I'm doing a lookup using MaxMind. But I'm wondering if the IPs may have moved country in the last 5 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some of the lovely people at Rackspace:

"The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) manages the IP address space allocations globally and delegates five regional Internet registries (RIRs) to allocate IP address blocks to local Internet registries (Internet service providers) and other entities.

I have seen occasions when big blocks were moved between countries, so I would say - yes, it's possible that and IP block can "swing" between countries but it is quite rare."

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is Yes. IP address allocation is renewable in yearly basis. So the owner can release the IP address back to pool and registry reallocate it to other users.

Therefore, many information changed since 5 years ago.